# Why is it throwing an incorrect systax error?

Tags: vbscript

The vb script I am using is throwing a message saying incorrect syntax on line 43 near ','. But I don't see why it would throw this message. Here is the code for where it is throwing the error:

```
Function getRS (sql)
      ' this loads the results of the sql statement into adoRecordset

      'response.write sql

      Set adoConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      Set adoRecordset= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
      adoRecordset.CursorType = adOpenStatic
      adoConnection.Open connectString
      adoRecordset.Open sql, adoConnection

   End Function
```

This line here is line 43: `adoRecordset.Open sql, adoConnection` but why would the comma cause incorrect syntax here?

Comment: Are you sure you have a connection? Where is connectString coming from? The code works for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. When I run the program it uses that same function for many other things. Just when I click ok on one of my pages it throws this problem.

Comment: maybe its an issue with the "sql" value, since its only happening on one of the pages.  can you post what its value is when it fails